# How is brain able to evoke almost real physical feelings in dreams?

Tags: dreams, brain

How does it do that?

Except for smell, I find brain being able to evoke almost real feels when we are in a dream. 
I was even able to make myself get *high* in a dream. And even in the dream, the brain was actually able to do a good job in giving me the persona of being a *High* person.

Also, why can't it evoke smell as well?

Comment: Where should I ask this question then? @RobinKramer

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with this question?